# Pandas: Melting columns containing tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas df with columns containing tuples of equal length.

```
L1 = [['ID1', ('key1a','key1b','key1c'), ('value1a','value1b','value1c')],
      ['ID2', ('key2a','key2b','key2c'), ('value2a','value2b','value2c')]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L1,columns=['ID','Key','Value'])

>>> df1
    ID                    Key                        Value
0  ID1  (key1a, key1b, key1c)  (value1a, value1b, value1c)
1  ID2  (key2a, key2b, key2c)  (value2a, value2b, value2c)
```

What's the easiest way to unfold this vertically as follows?:

```
    ID    Key    Value
0  ID1  key1a  value1a
1  ID1  key1b  value1b
2  ID1  key1c  value1c
3  ID2  key2a  value2a
4  ID2  key2b  value2b
5  ID2  key2c  value2c
6  ID3  key3a  value3a
7  ID3  key3b  value3b
8  ID3  key3c  value3c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows = []
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    [rows.append([row['ID'], key, val]) for key, val in zip(row['Key'], row['Value'])]

>>> pd.DataFrame(rows)
     0      1        2
0  ID1  key1a  value1a
1  ID1  key1b  value1b
2  ID1  key1c  value1c
3  ID2  key2a  value2a
4  ID2  key2b  value2b
5  ID2  key2c  value2c
```

**Timings (10k rows)**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['ID' + str(n) for n in range(10000)], 
    'Key': [tuple('key' + str(n) + letter for letter in ('a', 'b', 'c')) for n in range(10000)], 
    'Value': [tuple('value' + str(n) + letter for letter in ('a', 'b', 'c')) for n in range(10000)]})

%timeit df2.set_index('ID').stack().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack(0).T.reset_index()
1 loops, best of 3: 3.51 s per loop

%%timeit
rows = []
for _, row in df1.iterrows():
    [rows.append([row['ID'], key, val]) for key, val in zip(row['Key'], row['Value'])]
df_new = pd.DataFrame(rows)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.22 s per loop
```

Comment: This works, though in my console, row.Key and row.Value gives me errors like 'Series' object has no attribute 'Key'. If I use row['Key'] and row['Value'] syntax, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

quick solution

```
df1.set_index('ID').stack().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack(0).T.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Faster vectorized way would be using `np.repeat` and `np.concatenate`

```
In [2272]: pd.DataFrame({'ID': df1['ID'].values.repeat(df1['Key'].str.len()),
      ...:               'Key': np.concatenate(df1['Key']),
      ...:               'Value': np.concatenate(df1['Value'])})
Out[2272]:
    ID    Key    Value
0  ID1  key1a  value1a
1  ID1  key1b  value1b
2  ID1  key1c  value1c
3  ID2  key2a  value2a
4  ID2  key2b  value2b
5  ID2  key2c  value2c
```

---

**Timings**

```
In [2278]: df1.shape
Out[2278]: (10000, 3)

In [2275]: %%timeit
      ...:  pd.DataFrame({'ID': df1['ID'].values.repeat(df1['Key'].str.len()),
      ...:                'Key': np.concatenate(df1['Key']),
      ...:                'Value': np.concatenate(df1['Value'])})
      ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 355 ms per loop

In [2276]: %%timeit
      ...: rows = []
      ...: for _, row in df1.iterrows():
      ...:     [rows.append([row['ID'], key, val]) 
                for key, val in zip(row['Key'], row['Value'])]
      ...: pd.DataFrame(rows)
      ...:
1 loop, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop

In [2277]: %timeit df1.set_index('ID').stack().apply(
                     lambda x: pd.Series(x)).unstack(0).T.reset_index()
1 loop, best of 3: 3.87 s per loop
```

Comment: what is the np.concatenation doing?  I see your repeating the ID the len of the Key.

Answer (score 0):

create tuples combinations then build an dataframe using the combinations

```
L1 = [['ID1', ('key1a','key1b','key1c'), ('value1a','value1b','value1c')],
  ['ID2', ('key2a','key2b','key2c'), ('value2a','value2b','value2c')]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L1,columns=['ID','Key','Value'])
tuples=[]
for key,item in df1.iterrows():
    id=item['ID']
    for i in range(len(item['Key'])):
        key=item["Key"][i]
        value=item['Value'][i]
        tuples.append((id,key,value))
    
 df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(tuples,columns=['ID','Key','Value'])    
 print(df)

 output:
    ID    Key    Value
 0  ID1  key1a  value1a
 1  ID1  key1b  value1b
 2  ID1  key1c  value1c
 3  ID2  key2a  value2a
 4  ID2  key2b  value2b
 5  ID2  key2c  value2c
```